# Comparing timestamp variables from Java in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am creating a webpage using MVC model.
I'm a beginner and really new to JSP.
I created a questionnaire and when the deadline passed, I want to disable an input form.
I have these variables in Java.

```
public class List {
.
.
.

Timestamp endDate = 
new Timestamp(pc.getEndDate().getTime());   
    
Timestamp nowDate = 
new Timestamp(DateFactory.getInstance().getTime()); 
        
if (nowDate.after(endDate) ) {  
    list.dt();
   }

}
```

This is the code I have for JSP

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>

<c:if test="${'#{List.nowDate}' >= '#{List.endDate}'}">
    disabled
</c:if>
```

Is this the right way of writing the if statement in JSP?
I want to use nowDate and endDate variables from Java and just compare them with the if statement in JSP. Any ideas?

I appreciate your help!
Thanks a lot!

//Edit
This is the code I used for a request attribute but it didn't work.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            
            List list = new List(); 
            request.setAttribute("nowDate",nowDate);
            request.setAttribute("endDate",endDate);
        request..getRequestDispatcher("Cob00402A.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make sure there is a request attribute with name is "List" and the object has 2 properties named nowDate and endDate (getters/setters)

Fix your code:

```
<c:if test="${List.nowDate.time gte List.endDate.time}">
    disabled
</c:if>
```

Other JSTL operators:  gt, lt, lte, .... https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried but it didn`t work. I'm not sure that I write the correct request attribute or not.